# Symfony 2: Using Twig extension in form builder

Tags: php, symfony

I need to change the way a value or label is formatted with a custom filter. However, I need to do this from the form builder rather than in the twig template itself. In other words, when I build my form in the abstract type class, I need to be able to apply specific formatting.

Here is one application where this is needed:

Labels assigned to form elements are based on the database table field names. I need to be able to change how those labels are rendered, such as title case, or upper case, etc.

What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create a custom form field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html), that extend from choice or entity field type. Then you can customize [the template for the field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field)  applying filters or whatever you want.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.